# Clear JS Files Before Each Build With Gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am using Gulp to build my Angular app. I want to clear the app.js file before each new build otherwise everything inside app.js just gets doubled. I am trying to use gulp-rimraf to delete the file before concatenating all the pieces together again, but it's not working.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src('./public/javascripts/app.js')
  .pipe(rimraf())
  return gulp.src('./public/javascripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/'));
});

gulp.task('automate', function() {
    gulp.watch('./public/javascripts/*.js', ['scripts'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct,try with force in rimraf,might be if your file is in outside it may help

As a information rimraf is deprecated because of gulp is having del functionality to delete files and folder ,please look into it which is more easy to use

[Del](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md)

Answer (score 0):

Make another task, scripts-clear, and run it before scripts.

```
gulp.task('scripts-clear', function() {
  return gulp.src('./public/javascripts/app.js')
  .pipe(rimraf())
});

gulp.task('scripts', ['scripts-clear'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./public/javascripts/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/'));
});

gulp.task('automate', function() {
    gulp.watch('./public/javascripts/*.js', ['scripts'])
})
```